# I have trouble with Mysql Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib for encrypting data, My MySQL database's encoding is utf8-general-ci.
when I encrypt an string and save it to the table some of characters appears in '?' charachter. This make mistake when I want to decrypt it. 
What encoding should I use to have all of the characters?
please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encrypt your data to a binary string, it can no longer be stored in an UTF8 encoded string, since [some binary values/sequences are just not valid UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences).

Just base64 encode your string (or change the column type to a binary type) before storing it and things should work better.